# Slow performance of Python Polars in applying pl.element().filter

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have a polars df with a column of lists of string elements.
Those lists have empty elements that I need to filter out.
I used the following method:

```
df_main = df_main.with_columns( 
            df_main['ColumnList'].list.eval(
                pl.element().filter(
                    pl.element() != ""))
                    .alias('ColumnList') 
            )
```

However, it takes long time. (Around 12 seconds)
Another slow step is to strip the spaces from each element in the lists (Around 10 seconds):

```
df_main = df_main.with_columns(df_main['ColumnList'].list.eval(pl.element().str.strip_chars()).alias('ColumnList') )
```

I have tried to use "map_elements" with a custom function to perform both required functions but it took more than minute:

```
# Python
def FilterEmptyAndTrim(inList):
    lst1 = list(filter(lambda x : x != '' , inList)) # filter out empty items in the list
    return [s.strip() for s in lst1] # trim the usefull item in the list
df_main = df_main.with_columns(
    (df_main['ColumnList'].map_elements(FilterEmptyAndTrim)).alias('ColumnList'))
```

I have used the same exact custom function in pandas transform method but took 4 seconds only.

Here is a sample data like my data:

```
import polars as pl
df_main = pl.DataFrame({
    "ColumnList": [
        ['a ' , 'b' , '' ,' c',  'd'  ],
        ['a ' ,  '' ,' b', '' ,  'd'  ],
        ['a ' ,' b' , '' ,' c',  'd'  ],
        ['a ' , 'b' ,' b', '' , ' d ' ],]
})
df_main
```

Any way to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate. If I `df = pl.concat([df] * 250_000)` for a test case (1 million rows). `.list.eval(pl.element().filter(...).str.strip_chars())` (i.e. both steps) takes `640ms` - `.to_pandas().apply()` takes `3.9s` and `.map_elements()` takes so long that I had to kill it. Perhaps you could post a more realistic sample dataset / testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

You can use `set_difference` to filter out the empty strings and then either use `list.eval` or `explode/implode.over` to strip the begin/end whitespace. The former is slightly slower on this tiny test case but is more verbose

###### `explode/implode`

```
(
 df_main
 .with_row_index('i')
 .select(
     pl.col("ColumnList").list.set_difference(pl.lit(['']))
     .explode().str.strip_chars().implode().over('i')
     )
 .drop('i'))
```

###### `list.eval`

```
(
 df_main
 .select(
     pl.col("ColumnList").list.set_difference(pl.lit(['']))
     .list.eval(pl.element().str.strip_chars())
     ))
```

### Old answer

Explode is your friend.

For whatever reason, it turns out that `list.eval` is slow. Try to explode the list with a row index column. Despite the fact that this is many more lines of code and intuition might say it's got to be slower, it often is faster to avoid `list.eval`

```
(
    df_main
    .with_row_count('i')
    .explode('ColumnList')
    .filter(pl.col('ColumnList')!='')
    .with_columns(pl.col('ColumnList').str.strip_chars())
    .group_by('i',maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('ColumnList'))
    .drop('i')
    )
shape: (4, 1)
┌──────────────────────┐
│ ColumnList           │
│ ---                  │
│ list[str]            │
╞══════════════════════╡
│ ["a", "b", "c", "d"] │
│ ["a", "b", "d"]      │
│ ["a", "b", "c", "d"] │
│ ["a", "b", "c", "d"] │
└──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: not as fast as i expected but it is faster than Pandas by 25%. Many thanks Dean